# Webstorm debugging issue

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

My webstorm suddenly stopped debugging in Chrome. The port and settings are correct, or atlest they appear to me. This was working until two days back but stopped working today. I tried to retrace any changes to machine, but none of that would have impacted. So now here is what happens-

I start debug, it launches chrome, the jetbrains top debug bar shows in browser and closes as soon as the project loads up. So far I have created a new test proj, reinstalled WS, JRE, JDK, replaced JRE folder inside WS folder, rebooted machine but all to no avail.

I looked at the log files and here is what it generates-

```
2014-10-10 22:39:29,172 [6742940]  ERROR - g.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager - Unterminated string at line 1 column 89981 

    com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 89981
        at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.b(JsonReaderEx.java:1458)
        at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.b(JsonReaderEx.java:1002)
        at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.nextName(JsonReaderEx.java:680)
        at org.jetbrains.io.JsonReaderEx.nextNameAsCharSequence(JsonReaderEx.java:691)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.protocol.WipProtocolReaderImpl$M169.(WipProtocolReaderImpl.java:6511)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.protocol.WipProtocolReaderImpl$M169F.read(WipProtocolReaderImpl.java:7239)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.protocol.WipProtocolReaderImpl$M169F.read(WipProtocolReaderImpl.java:7236)
        at org.jetbrains.jsonProtocol.JsonReaders.readObjectArray(JsonReaders.java:167)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.protocol.WipProtocolReaderImpl$M166.(WipProtocolReaderImpl.java:6404)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.protocol.WipProtocolReaderImpl.readRuntimeGetPropertiesResult(WipProtocolReaderImpl.java:601)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.protocol.ProtocolResponseReader.readResult(ProtocolResponseReader.java:353)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.WipCommandProcessor.readResult(WipCommandProcessor.java:108)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.WipCommandProcessor.readResult(WipCommandProcessor.java:18)
        at org.jetbrains.rpc.CommandCallbackWithResponseBase.onSuccess(CommandCallbackWithResponseBase.java:20)
        at org.jetbrains.wip.WipCommandProcessor.commandResultReceived(WipCommandProcessor.java:36)
        at com.intellij.chromeConnector.extension.DebuggerService$3.consume(DebuggerService.java:137)
        at com.intellij.chromeConnector.extension.DebuggerService$3.consume(DebuggerService.java:132)
        at com.intellij.chromeConnector.extension.JbWipVm$1.consume(JbWipVm.java:21)
        at com.intellij.chromeConnector.extension.JbWipVm$1.consume(JbWipVm.java:18)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:110)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:107)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:104)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:215)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3.run(QueueProcessor.java:212)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,173 [6742941]  ERROR - g.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager - WebStorm 8.0.4  Build #WS-135.1063 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,174 [6742942]  ERROR - g.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager - JDK: 1.7.0_40 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,174 [6742942]  ERROR - g.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,174 [6742942]  ERROR - g.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,174 [6742942]  ERROR - g.jetbrains.rpc.MessageManager - OS: Windows 7 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,184 [6742952]  ERROR - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.ContinuationWebSocketFrame frame types not supported 
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.ContinuationWebSocketFrame frame types not supported
        at org.jetbrains.io.webSocket.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:47)
        at org.jetbrains.io.webSocket.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:10)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:139)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:332)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:156)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:139)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:332)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:117)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:494)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:461)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:799)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,185 [6742953]  ERROR - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - WebStorm 8.0.4  Build #WS-135.1063 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,185 [6742953]  ERROR - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - JDK: 1.7.0_40 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,185 [6742953]  ERROR - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,185 [6742953]  ERROR - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,185 [6742953]  ERROR - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - OS: Windows 7 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,186 [6742954]   INFO - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - Browser disconnected: Chrome (chrome) 
    2014-10-10 22:39:29,247 [6743015]   INFO - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - Browser connected: version 2.0.7, CHROME
```

Comment: WebStorm and Chrome versions?

Comment: WebStorm 8.0.4  Build #WS-135.1063 
JDK: 1.7.0_40 
OS: Windows 7 
Chrome (chrome) version 2.0.7, CHROME

Comment: I meant: Google Chrome version. Recent version is 38 .. -- your 2.0.7 looks either wrong or extremely old.

Comment: In any case: Chrome has recently (v37) updated their protocols .. which made WebStorm v8 incompatible. So either try v9 EAP build or downgrade Chrome to v36 (e.g. install it separately, disable auto-updates and use it for development only). v9 EAP -- see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/10/webstorm-9-beta-139-12-inline-variables-view-and-fixes/

Comment: Thank you for the help. Upgrading to webstorm 9 beta worked out. If you want to add this as an answer, I will mark it as acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that upgrading to Webstorm v9 EAP solved this problem for me:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP

I had the same symptoms.  Was debugging fine a couple days ago using webstorm 8.04.

My Chrome must have auto-updated.  As of this writing I have chrome 38.0.2125.101 and webstorm 8.04 was not compatible with it (it would seem to start debugging OK but then randomly say that the browser disconnected after about 5 seconds).

After upgrading to Webstorm v9 via the EAP link above I can debug again.